# Function call inside a for loop breaks the loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a small fiddle I was experimenting with, and I noticed calling a function inside a for loop condition was stopping the loop. Basically, initially I wanted to do this:

```
// add event listeners to tabs
for (i=0;i<tabs.length;i++) {
    tabs[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var tab = event.target;
        selectPage(tab.dataset.tab);
        changeTab(tab);
    });
    if (tabs[i].classList.contains('active')) {
        selectPage(tabs[i].dataset.tab);
    }
}
```

But, ended up having to do this to make it work:

```
// add event listeners to tabs
for (i=0;i<tabs.length;i++) {
    tabs[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var tab = event.target;
        selectPage(tab.dataset.tab);
        changeTab(tab);
    });
}
// find active class and set page
for (i=0;i<tabs.length;i++) {
  if (tabs[i].classList.contains('active')) {
     selectPage(tabs[i].dataset.tab);
  }
}
```

Here is a link to the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/railsarr/q2vzLh21/)

Thanks for any help in advance, I feel there is something fundamental here I'm not getting. Thanks

Comment: That's impossible!

Comment: Ok, could you explain...

Comment: Look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lesson 0: use [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) or similar tools to check your code for trivial errors before spending sleepless nights here on SO and/or in debugging tools.

Lesson 1: localize your variables.

Your problem is with variable `i` that's global - hence reused by both your global code and `selectPage` function. The latter sets its value to `tabs.length`, ending up the loop prematurely.

Just replace `i = 0` with `var i = 0` at each `for` expression.

Comment: Thank you, for the thorough answer, explanation, and suggesting using ESLint!

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the x variable using let.

```
// add event listeners to tabs
for (let i=0;i<tabs.length;i++) {
    tabs[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var tab = event.target;
    selectPage(tab.dataset.tab);
    changeTab(tab);
  });
  if (tabs[i].classList.contains('active')) {
    selectPage(tabs[i].dataset.tab);
  }
}
```

Comment: up for suggesting let

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion. I changed vars to let. I'm brushing up on Vanilla JS while learning React, I have become to reliant on jQuery.